# How to repeat a function n times

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to write a function in python that is like:

```
def repeated(f, n):
    ...
```

where `f` is a function that takes one argument and `n` is a positive integer.

For example if I defined square as:

```
def square(x):
    return x * x
```

and I called

```
repeated(square, 2)(3)
```

this would square 3, 2 times.

Answer (score 26):

That should do it:

```
 def repeated(f, n):
     def rfun(p):
         return reduce(lambda x, _: f(x), xrange(n), p)
     return rfun

 def square(x):
     print "square(%d)" % x
     return x * x

 print repeated(square, 5)(3)
```

output:

```
 square(3)
 square(9)
 square(81)
 square(6561)
 square(43046721)
 1853020188851841
```

or `lambda`-less?

```
def repeated(f, n):
    def rfun(p):
        acc = p
        for _ in xrange(n):
            acc = f(acc)
        return acc
    return rfun
```

Answer (score 9):

Using `reduce` and lamba.
Build a tuple starting with your parameter, followed by all functions you want to call:

```
>>> path = "/a/b/c/d/e/f"
>>> reduce(lambda val,func: func(val), (path,) + (os.path.dirname,) * 3)
"/a/b/c"
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
def repeat(f, n):
     if n==0:
             return (lambda x: x)
     return (lambda x: f (repeat(f, n-1)(x)))
```

Comment: It probably does, but I think it shows what the OP wants to construct.

Comment: If you change the check to `n == 0` and return `lambda x: x` in that case you make your approach work for zero, too.

Answer (score 2):

Use an itertools recipe called `repeatfunc` that performs this operation.

**Given**

```
def square(x):
    """Return the square of a value."""
    return x * x
```

**Code**

From [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def repeatfunc(func, times=None, *args):
    """Repeat calls to func with specified arguments.

    Example:  repeatfunc(random.random)
    """
    if times is None:
        return starmap(func, repeat(args))
    return starmap(func, repeat(args, times))
```

**Demo**

Optional: You can use a third-party library, [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools), that conveniently implements these recipes:

```
import more_itertools as mit


list(mit.repeatfunc(square, 2, 3))
# [9, 9]
```

Install via `> pip install more_itertools`

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce and itertools.repeat (as Marcin suggested):

```
from itertools import repeat
from functools import reduce # necessary for python3

def repeated(func, n):
    def apply(x, f):
        return f(x)
    def ret(x):
        return reduce(apply, repeat(func, n), x)
    return ret
```

You can use it as follows:

```
>>> repeated(os.path.dirname, 3)('/a/b/c/d/e/f')
'/a/b/c'

>>> repeated(square, 5)(3)
1853020188851841
```

(after importing `os` or defining `square` respectively)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want function composition:

```
def compose(f, x, n):
  if n == 0:
    return x
  return compose(f, f(x), n - 1)

def square(x):
  return pow(x, 2)

y = compose(square, 3, 2)
print y
```

Comment: Note that OP is asking for a higher-order function. You have create a recursive function that repeatedly applies the same function. Not quite the same.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889688/3080723) suggests `def compose(f, x, n): return functools.reduce( lambda x, _: f(x), range(n), x)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recipe using `reduce`:

```
def power(f, p, myapply = lambda init, g:g(init)):
    ff = (f,)*p # tuple of length p containing only f in each slot
    return lambda x:reduce(myapply, ff, x)

def square(x):
    return x * x

power(square, 2)(3)
#=> 81
```

I call this `power`, because this is literally what the power function does, with composition replacing multiplication.

`(f,)*p` creates a tuple of length `p` filled with `f` in every index. If you wanted to get fancy, you would use a generator to generate such a sequence (see `itertools`) - but note it would have to be created inside the lambda.

`myapply` is defined in the parameter list so that it is only created once.

Comment: For big p this has the downside to explicitly construct a tuple of length n.

Comment: @UweKleine-König Yes, that's why 5 years ago I mentioned using itertools generators as an alternative.