# Equivalent of Mathematica Nest function in Python

Tags: python, function, wolfram-mathematica

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to repeat a function n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359828/how-to-repeat-a-function-n-times)

Mathematica's Nest function Definition is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nest.html)
What's the eqv. in Python?

Like this: **nest(f, x, 2) ----> f(f(x))**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359828/how-to-repeat-a-function-n-times — Stack Overflow is preventing me from adding this as  an answer these days.  Sigh.

Comment: @NicholasRiley: What do you mean?

Comment: I want to know how to write [NestList][1] http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestList.html