# Repeat function python

Tags: python

I'm stuck at higher-order functions in python. I need to write a repeat function `repeat` that applies the function `f` `n` times on a given argument `x`.

For example, `repeat(f, 3, x)` is `f(f(f(x)))`.

This is what I have:

```
def repeat(f,n,x):
    if n==0:
        return f(x)
    else:
        return repeat(f,n-1,x)
```

When I try to assert the following line:

```
plus = lambda x,y: repeat(lambda z:z+1,x,y)
assert plus(2,2) == 4
```

It gives me an `AssertionError`. I read about [How to repeat a function n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359828/how-to-repeat-a-function-n-times) but I need to have it done in this way and I can't figure it out...

Comment: Is the `f(x)` function returning anything? Unless otherwise specified, it will return `None`

Comment: And you want get the result of the last application of `f(x)`?

Comment: Shouldn't `repeat` return something like `return f(repeat(f,n-1,x))`?

Comment: As a simpler example, try `plus(0,2)`, which should be 2 but your code gives 3. It doesn't recurse, so it should be easy to debug.

Comment: Instead of just `assert`ing, you can try looking at the actual return value of `plus`. Try it with different inputs and it will be easy to see what the problem is.

Comment: Close-voting, as the question is not very clear or needs a lot of clarifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You are recursing the wrong number of times (if `n == 1`, the function should be called once); and
2. You aren't calling `f` on the returned value from the recursive call, so the function is only ever applied once.

Try:

```
def repeat(f, n, x):
    if n == 1: # note 1, not 0
        return f(x)
    else:
        return f(repeat(f, n-1, x)) # call f with returned value
```

or, alternatively:

```
def repeat(f, n, x):
    if n == 0:
        return x # note x, not f(x)
    else:
        return f(repeat(f, n-1, x)) # call f with returned value
```

(thanks to @Kevin for the latter, which supports `n == 0`).

Example:

```
>>> repeat(lambda z: z + 1, 2, 2)
4
>>> assert repeat(lambda z: z * 2, 4, 3) == 3 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
>>>
```

Comment: It may be preferable to do `if n == 0: return x` rather than `if n == 1: return f(x)`. That way, `plus(0,2)` will still work.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a very simple error there, in the else block you are just passing x along without doing anything to it. Also you are applying x when n == 0, don't do that.

```
def repeat(f,n,x):
    """
    >>> repeat(lambda x: x+1, 2, 0)
    2
    """
    return repeat(f, n-1, f(x)) if n > 0 else x
```