# Defining a function that returns another function as an output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define a function `f()` that will use a function `g()` `n` times - `f(g(x), n)` - to modify a single input. The thing is, I want to make it so that `f(g(x), n)` will output another function `k()`, such that `k(a)` will give me the final result. For example:

```
square = lambda x : x*x
test = f(square, 2)
test(2) = (2^2)^2 = 16
```

I have had many attempts, but most of the time a `TypeError` would occur.

Here is one of my attempts:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

def mainfunc(function, no_of_times):
    def func(x):
        if no_of_times == 0:
            return x
        else:
            return function(mainfunc(function, no_of_times - 1))
    return func

test = mainfunc(square, 2)

print(test(2))
```

Can I have some advice on whether I have had the correct approach? If not, what should I do?

Comment: You can immediately test that this is *not* the correct approach, otherwise it would not fail with a TypeError. Is there any reason why you attempt this with recursion? This can very easily be solved with a loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat function python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264420/repeat-function-python)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I am studying the first few chapters of Python, and the problem comes up in the recursion chapter so I thought it might be the way. I did not think of using a loop, maybe I will try now, thank you. Thank you also for the second comment but it does not specifically address my problem

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume `function` and `no_of_times` are just global names. A function that applies `function` `no_of_times` times to a given value is easy to implement:

```
 def func(x):
     for _ in range(no_of_times):
         x = function(x)
     return x
```

But you want a function `f` that returns such a function. And also, `function` and `no_of_times` shall be parameters of `f`, not global variables. So simply wrap the `func` definition in the function `f` with the wanted signature and return the resulting inner function:

```
def f(function, no_of_times):
     def func(x):
         for _ in range(no_of_times):
             x = function(x)
         return x
     return func
```

This works as wanted:

```
>>> f(lambda x: x*x, 2)(2)
16

>>> g = lambda x: x*x
>>> k = f(g, 2)
>>> k(2)
16

>>> g = lambda x: f'g({x})'
>>> k = f(g, 5)
>>> k('spam')
'g(g(g(g(g(spam)))))'
```

Implementing the inner function `func` in a functional style is left as an exercise to the reader. (And also wasn't what the question asked for.)

Comment: Nice! BTW this is called a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Yes, `func` (or `k`) is a closure. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with your code:

1. You need to return `1` when you want to run the function `zero` times.
2. In the recursive part of `mainfunc` you use `function(mainfunc(function, no_of_times - 1))`. The use of the outer `function` is incorrect as you are calling your `square` function with a function object as its argument when it expects an `int`.That is why you get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'function'`.
3. In the recursive part of the function you need `square(x) * mainfunc(function, no_of_times - 1)(x)`.

Two points to note regarding point 3:

- Your `mainfunc` returns `func` which expects an `int` as its argument. Thus, when you recurse you need to call it as follows: `mainfunc(function, no_of_times - 1)(x)`.
- Since you are now recursing `no_of_times -1` you need to multiply by `function(x)` to ensure that your recursive function works as intended.

---

```
def square(x):
    return x * x


def mainfunc(function, no_of_times):
    def func(x):
        if no_of_times == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return function(x) * mainfunc(function, no_of_times - 1)(x)

    return func


test = mainfunc(square, 3)

print(test(3))
```

Output: `64`

Comment: I don't think `mainfunc` should be using `square` (or for that matter, the multiplication operator `*`) directly. It's supposed to remain general.

Comment: hmm, good point. Replaced `square(x)` by `function(x)` in `mainfunc`. Not so sure about the `*` operator. How else are we supposed to recurse?