# how do I apply a function n times?

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

Suppose for example I have a function that accepts one argument and returns a result of the same type:

```
def increment(x):
    return x + 1
```

How can I make a higher-order function `repeat` that can create a new function, which applies the above function a specified number of times?

For example, if I call `repeat(increment, 5)(x)`, I should get the same result as `increment(increment(increment(increment(increment(x)))))`.

Comment: If you're trying to learn more about higher order functions, function composition and currying in general, then I suggest taking a look at the `functools` module. It has a lot of goodies :)

Comment: I had problems in extending any of the proposed solutions to deal with more than one function argument. After passing 3-tupel instead of 3 arguments it worked:

    def _f(_t):
        return (_t[0]**2+_t[1])%_t[2]

    def _repeat(_func, _m, _t):
        for _i in range(_m):
            _t = (_func(_t), _t[1], _t[2])
        return _t[0]

    S = 894488611079900130
    A = 1
    N = (2**31-1)**2
    print(_repeat(_f, 27081, (2, A, N)) == S)

Comment: Readable python: [apply_funtion_n_times.py.tx](https://stamm-wilbrandt.de/apply_funtion_n_times.py.txt)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359828/how-to-repeat-a-function-n-times .

Comment: In fact, I'm pretty sure this should be a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 8):

Well, there's the iterative approach:

```
def repeat(f, n):
    def new_fn(x):
        for _ in range(n):
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return new_fn

higher_fn = repeat(lambda x: x+3, 5)

higher_fn(2)    # => 17 == (((((2 + 3) + 3) + 3) + 3) + 3)
```

and the compositional approach:

```
def repeat(f, n):
    new_fn_str = "lambda x: {}x{}".format("f(" * n, ")" * n)
    new_fn     = eval(new_fn_str, {"f": f})
    return new_fn
```

which results in exactly the same thing but may be slightly faster.

Comment: Isn't doing something like this with eval usually discouraged? Or is it not a security problem since no strings are introduced to eval from elsewhere?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a simple for loop.

```
>>> def integer_inc(x):
...     return x + 1
... 
>>> def repeat(func, n, x):
...     for i in range(n):
...         x = func(x)
...     return x
... 
>>> repeat(integer_inc, 5, 1)
6
>>>
```

Comment: The name `integer` for a function that *increments* is rather confusing. Even though the OP used it.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, yes agreed. Edited the answer.

Comment: hi5 bratha! :) Keep up the great work.

Answer (score 4):

We also have the recursive implementation:

```
def repeat(f, n):
    if n == 1:
        return f
    else:
        return lambda x: f(repeat(f,n-1)(x))
```

Comment: This results in a max recusion error for `n = 0`. Maybe a good way to solve this is by adding a case `if n == 0: return lambda x: x`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a decorator,

```
from functools import wraps


def repeat(n=1):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(args):
            args = func(args)
            for i in xrange(n-1):
                args = func(args)
            return args
        return wrapper
    return decorator

if __name__ == "__main__":
    @repeat(n=6)
    def test(a):
        print a
        return a+1
    test(1)
```