# How to write this product function in a more elegant way?

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have a very simple function which I'm sure can be improved. My goal is to create a matrix which is a chain of tensors products of one particular matrix. My current solution is

```
def make_layer_identity(M, J):
    out = J
    if M > 1:
        for i in range(M-1):
            out = np.kron(out, J)
    return out
```

I'm sure there is a better, clearer way of doing this. I'm having trouble with various functions which need to be iterative, (such as here needing to take repeated `kron` products), but need initialisation.

Comment: Maybe a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359828/how-to-repeat-a-function-n-times https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259967/how-do-i-apply-a-function-n-times/28260210 and if you think the solutions given there are inefficient because your `M` can be very large, I suggest reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring and trying to apply the idea to your problem.

Comment: Both helpful comments, thanks. I didn't know about codereview - in future I'll post this sort of thing there.