# Applying/Composing a function N times to a pandas column, N being different for each row

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have this simple pandas.DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
  columns=['quantity', 'value'],
  data=[[1, 12.5], [3, 18.0]]
)

>>> print(df)
   quantity  value
0         1   12.5
1         3   18.0
```

I would like to create a new column, say `modified_value`, that applies a function N times to the `value` column, N being the `quantity` column.
Suppose that function is `new_value = round(value/2, 1)`, the expected result would be:

```
   quantity  value  modified_value
0         1   12.5            6.2   # applied 1 time
1         3   9.0             1.1   # applied 3 times, 9.0 -> 4.5 -> 2.2 -> 1.1
```

What would be an elegant/vectorized way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom `repeat` function, then use apply:

```
def repeat(func, x, n):
    ret = x
    for i in range(int(n)):
        ret = func(ret)

    return ret

def my_func(val): return round(val/2, 1)

df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: repeat(my_func, x['value'], x['quantity']), 
                         axis=1)

# or without apply
# df['new_col'] = [repeat(my_func, v, n) for v,n in zip(df['value'], df['quantity'])]
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works like a charm. Out of curiosity, why would you use `apply` over a list comprehension?

Comment: `apply` is convenient sometimes. For example, if your function takes more values from a row, it could be tiresome to type `zip(df['col1'], df['col2'],...)`. And to many people `df.apply(func, axis=1)` is more readable than `[func(row) for id, row in df.iterrows()]`. Plus, `apply` returns a series with corresponding index, which can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
def repeated(f, n):
    def rfun(p):
        return reduce(lambda x, _: f(x), range(n), p)
    return rfun
```

---

```
def myfunc(value): return  round(value/2, 1)
```

---

```
df['modified_valued'] = df.apply(lambda x: repeated(myfunc,
                                                    int(x['quantity']))(x['value']),
                                 axis=1)
```

We can also use list comprehension instead `apply`

```
df['modified_valued'] = [repeated(myfunc, int(quantity))(value) 
                         for quantity, value in zip (df['quantity'], df['value'])]
```

**Output**

```
   quantity  value  modified_valued
0         1   12.5              6.2
1         3   18.0              2.2
```

Comment: apply is another layout of for loop *elegant/vectorized*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Because @quang-hoang proposed a solution without additional import, I tested his first, and it worked. I understand that yours is based on the same concept, so I'm sure it works too.

Comment: The map, reduce and filter functions work very well and possibly better than for loops, so I suggested using reduce, it also provides a simpler syntax. 
this solution is supported by the community, communityhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359828/how-to-repeat-a-function-n-times/45899449#45899449