# Fibonacci sequence using reduce method

Tags: python, recursion, lambda, reduce

So, I saw someone using the reduce method to calculate the Fibonacci sequence.
Here is his idea: (1,0) , (1,1) , (2,1) , (3,2) , (5,3) corresponds to
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 .......

and the code looks like this

```
def fib_reduce(n):
    initial =(1,0)
    dummy = range(n)
    fib_n = reduce(lambda prev ,b : (prev[0] + prev[1], prev[0]),
                   dummy,
                   initial)
    
    return fib_n[0]
```

I understand the `(prev[0] + prev[1] , prev[0])` which is like
`a, b = b, b + a`.
However, I don't understand what this `b` stands for ?

May someone please explain this `b`?

Comment: I don't see any recursion here.

Comment: Note that this is *not* a recursive algorithm. While ``reduce`` can be implemented recursively, in Python it is effectively a ``for`` loop ([pure Python implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b121a4a45ff4bab8812a9b26ceffe5ad642f5d5a/Lib/functools.py#L253), [C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/37834136d0afe51d274bfc79d8705514cbe73727/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L650)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Repeatedly applying a function using `reduce`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23795000/3080723) suggests writing up your own function `repeated` to repeatedly apply a function, rather than calling `reduce` with a dummy second argument.

We still use `reduce`, but in a more functional manner and with `itertools.repeat`.

```py
from itertools import repeat
from functools import reduce

def repeated(func, n):
    def apply(x, f):
        return f(x)
    def ret(x):
        return reduce(apply, repeat(func, n), x)
    return ret

def fibonacci(n):
  get_next_pair = lambda p: (sum(p), p[0])
  first_pair = (1, 0)
  return repeated(get_next_pair, n)(first_pair)[1]

print(fibonacci(0), fibonacci(1), fibonacci(11))
# 0 1 89
```

### Repeatedly apply a linear function using linear algebra

The function `lambda a,b: b,a+b` which you want to apply happens to be a linear function. It can be represented by a 2*2 matrix. Repeatedly applying the function to a two-element tuple is the same as repeatedly multiplying a two-element vector by the matrix.

This is cool, because taking the power of a matrix is much, much faster than repeatedly applying a function.

```py
import numpy as np

def fibonacci(n):
  return np.linalg.matrix_power(np.array([[0, 1],[1,1]]), n).dot(np.array([0,1]))[0]

print(fibonacci(0), fibonacci(1), fibonacci(11))
# 0 1 89
```

If you don't like one-liners, here is the same function decomposed on a few lines with more explicit variable names:

```py
import numpy as np

def fibonacci(n):
  next_pair_matrix = np.array([[0, 1],[1,1]])
  matrix_to_the_nth = np.linalg.matrix_power(next_pair_matrix, n)
  first_pair_vector = np.array([0,1])
  nth_pair_vector = matrix_to_the_nth.dot(first_pair_vector)
  return nth_pair_vector[0]

print(fibonacci(0), fibonacci(1), fibonacci(11))
# 0 1 89
```

Comment: Comparing my `reduce` version with the `for`-loop version from your answer by running `t0 = time.perf_counter(); y = fibonacci(10000); t1 = time.perf_counter()` ten times and taking the average, I get `1.56ms` for the for-loop; `3.72ms` for the reduce; and `0.125ms` for the matrix.

Comment: With `fibonacci(100000)` I get: `for`loop 74.4ms; `reduce` 153.4ms; matrix 0.14ms.

Comment: Oops, you can forget the time of the matrix version. Apparently the for-loop and reduce versions both use python's big ints, but the matrix version doesn't and returns an incorrect result for fib(100000).