# Does Python have a `nest` function like Mathematica?

Tags: python, function, recursion, functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica has a convenient [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) function for repeatedly evaluating `f(f(f(f(...f(n)))))`. Not something you need every day, but occasionally useful. Here is a trivial implementation:

```
def nest(f, expr, n):
    assert n >= 0
    if n == 0:
        return expr
    else:
        return f(nest(f, expr, n - 1))
```

```
>>> nest(lambda x: (1 + x) ** 2, 1, 3)
676
```

Is there a Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: A more conveniant approach to this is probably to consider using `reduce` pattern. the `map/reduce` pattern can easily be distributed and your problem can be expressed as a `reduce` expression (in a slightly different on more general way).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat a function n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359828/how-to-repeat-a-function-n-times); In particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23795000/3080723)

Comment: Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889688/3080723) to a different question suggests `def compose(f, x, n): return functools.reduce( lambda x, _: f(x), range(n), x)`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps if you like these sorts of things, you can look into [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

def nest(f, expr, n):
    return reduce(lambda x, _: f(x), range(n), expr)
```

```
>>> nest(lambda x: (1 + x) ** 2, 1, 3)
676
```

Answer (score 2):

Talking Pythonic, which is a bit of an opinion-based concept, I'd say a simple iterative implementation is more readable ([Readability being a core Python principle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)) than `reduce`-based or recursive approaches:

```
def nest(f, expr, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        expr = f(expr)
    return expr
```

Certainly, I will not have to stare down what's happening here as much as in the other cases. If it is, however, brevity you're after, you can go with a conditional expression:

```
def nest(f, expr, n):
    return f(nest(f, expr, n - 1)) if n else expr
```

Comment: I actually totally agree with you. I offered a `reduce` answer as a bit of a tongue-in-cheek comment. In fact, I like this (dated, but related) [post](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) by Guido Himself. (Also, in my defense, I've been scarred for life by more than a decade of developing map-reduce algorithms for petabytes-scale problems --I confess it was fun, though).

Comment: I meant no criticism (one of your upticks is from me). I like the creative use of `reduce` there. And if the OP is into that sort of functional voodoo, it might be right up their alley =)