# Applying a function to itself multiple times in python

Tags: python

According to the documentation of [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), the `reduce` method is useful for

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value. For example, `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calculates `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`.

Now,  I wanted to have a single valued function, I could make the workaround of creating a lambda to ignore an input:

```
from os.path import dirname
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda d, _: dirname(d), range(3), __file__)
```

Is there an alternative to `reduce` that avoids this workaround? In Mathematica there is the [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) function, is there no analogue in python?

Comment: What are you expecting `dirname(0)` to return? Why not just use `[__file__] + [dirname(i) for i in range(3)]`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Getting the dir path 3 levels up from the current file path?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen for the example yes, but in practice I wanted an equivalent of the Nest function from Mathematica.

Comment: As someone points out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65345552/712649), you can use a simple `for` loop to re-apply the function the required number of times.

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in, but it's simple to write your own `def nest` that uses the code you wrote.

Comment: Just use a for-loop

Comment: @Barmar I use similar stuff to this as boilerplate in many places (something just to add paths to my PYTHONPATH), having a concise one-liner would be much helpful. This is also why I don't want to define a for-loop.

Comment: If you define a function, it becomes a one-liner when you call the function.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but in Python it is recommended to avoid loops whenever possible for performance reasons. For example, your example code could be written as `Path(__file__).parents[2]` with [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Of course, you can't get rid of all the loops. But if you choose loops just because you can, that's bad practice.

Comment: @ken that is absolutely **not true**. That only applies to `numpy`. For loops are pretty much as fast as other constructs in python, `map`, `filter`, `reduce` and comprehensions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is not what I meant. I mean loops in a broad sense, including `map`, `filter`, `reduce` and comprehensions, not just `for` and `while` statements. More specifically, I am talking about a design philosophy that favors the repetition of small (pure Python) code fragments, even if there are other suitable implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pathlib to split the parts and os.path.join to put the parts you want back together:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

print(os.path.join(*Path(__file__).parts[:-3]))
```

[EDIT] there could be a more generalized way to use reduce that will make it closer to the nest approach:

```
reduce(lambda p,f:f(p),[dirname]*3,__file__)
```

This uses the same lambda for any function and places the function and repetitions (nesting levels) in the iterator part of reduce.

Comment: interesting ideia, but I need this for more stuff than just the dirname case

Answer (score 1):

I am going to ignore the paths example, and instead focus entirely on python's equivalent of that `nest` function, as that appears to be your main question. If I understand the Mathematica docs correctly, what you are looking at is a different specific application of a so-called `fold`

python's `reduce` is a left-wise fold. In fact, it has near feature-parity with Haskell's `foldl` Mathematica's `Nest` instead is a specific type of right-wise fold, which does not exist in python's standard library. The equivilant of `foldr` in python would be the very ugly (using the Mathematica naming convention):

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

def foldr(fs: List[Callable], expr: T) -> T:
    return reduce(lambda result, f: f(result), fs, expr)
```

`Nest` could then be implemented as:

```py
def nest(f: Callable, expr: T, n: int) -> T:
    return foldr([f]*n, expr)
```

As far as I am aware, there is no right-fold in Python's std, and you need to keep due with this very ugly alternative. `Nest` can probably be implemented a bit cleaner, but I personally think that making it an application of a right-fold is the most readable option, if you ignore how ugly `foldr` is.

of course, both can also be done in a non-functional style:

```py
def foldr(fs: List[Callable], expr: T) -> T:
    for f in fs:
        expr = f(expr)
    return expr

def nest(f: Callable, expr: T, n: int) -> T:
    for _ in range(n):
        expr = f(expr)
    return expr
```

But, as you have seen me referencing Haskell in this answer, you might have already guessed I quite dislike those. :P

I hope that helps! :-)